# ng update: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0: TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular 5 and I'm trying to migrate to angular 6. If I run `ng update, I get the following error:

> Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0 TF400813: Resource not
>   available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out by reading [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10624#issuecomment-386581543), that the problem is that I'm using a private npm repository and, if the `package.json` has packages that depends on this private repository, I will get this error.

The solution was to remove this dependence, run the `ng update` and then put again the dependecies on `package.json` and the update worked.